# I cannot get my computer's date, only its time

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I want my C# application to get the time and date of my computer but it only gets the time not the date so here is the code.

```
ApareceCrudLib b = new ApareceCrudLib("localhost", "root", "", "cashieringdb");
string theDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
string query = "INSERT INTO sales (price, user, date) " +
    "VALUES(" +
    "'" + txtQuant.Text + "'," +
    "'" + txtLog.Text +"'," +
    "'" + theDate +"')";
b.mysqlInsert(query);
```

Here is my MySql database result. (Never mind the lordens that's the user mistakenly encircled).

[image]

Here is my date structure set to Varchar and length/values to 10.

[image]

Anyway I just notice the code TimeString and DateString in my C# application is there a way to get them both like Time and Date String?

Comment: Anyway I just notice the code TimeString and DateString in my C# application is there a way to get the both like Time and Date String?

Answer (score 5):

First, don't store the date as string in your database. Use the proper datatype for it, `DATE` or `DATETIME`.

Second, You're `INSERT` statement is weak. It is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. The values **Must** be parameterized.

code snippet,

```
string connStr = "connection string here";
string insertStr = @"INSERT INTO sales (price, user, date)
                        VALUES (@price, @user, @date)";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
{
    using (MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.text;
        comm.CommandText = insertStr;
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", txtQuant.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtLog.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(MySqlException ex)
        {
            // don't hide the exception
            // do something
            // ex.ToString()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont worry for security since I will not get this online, the application is only accessible with in our lan by my trusted users. I mean this is for home sharing and storing database.

Comment: do you mean the type in my MySql database if that is what you mean I will try changing it.

Comment: yes. Use proper data type for the values stored in the database.

Comment: also, use [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.datetime.now.aspx) only

Comment: @Jayseer even if it is only used on home, aside from `SQL Injection`, you are also prone from exceptions. What if I pass a string with single quote on it (*indicator of SQL Injection*) like `Johnny's Place` which will eventually break you insert statement string.